# Локальное сохранение переменной

Tags: javascript

есть код

```html
<button onclick="plusScore()">Добавить очки</button>
<button onclick="balanceUser()"> баланс </button>
<!--scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var score = 0

  function plusScore() {
    score = score + 100
    alert('Очки пополнены!')
  }

  function balanceUser() {
    alert('Твой баланс ' + score)
  }
</script>
```

как сделать так, чтобы значение переменной `score` сохранилось после закрытия браузера, и после его открытия показался тот же баланс, который сохранился?

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `localstorage` или `session` или `cookie` для сохранения переменной в зависимости от потребностей.
Так же Вам стоит убрать `var score = 0` чтобы прибавлять данные к сохранённому значению. 
Пример с комментариями:

```
<button onclick="plusScore()">Добавить очки</button>
<button onclick="balanceUser()"> баланс </button>
<!--scripts-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function plusScore() {
        var score = localStorage.getItem('Score'); //Получаем значение из переменной, если её нет - будет null
        score = +score + 100; // Значение score приводим к числу и к этому значению прибавляем 100
        console.log(score);
        localStorage.setItem('Score', score); //Сохраняем в localstorage
    }

    function balanceUser() {
        var scor = localStorage.getItem('Score'); //Получаем значение из localstorage
        console.log(scor);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Извините, но есть ли возможность удаления значения из переменной `scor` или `score` с помощью js ?

Comment: @Володимер Да. storage.removeItem("Score");